# how to include the variables inside hx-vals?

Tags: thymeleaf, htmx

I have an input tag that i use for searching.

```
<input id="keyword" type="search" name="keyword" th:value="${keyword}">
```

Now I have a hx-get in a div.

```
 <div hx-trigger="load, every 15s" 
     hx-get="/user-list" hx-vals='{"keyword":"admin"'
      hx-target="this"></div>
```

generated url: `/user-list?keyword=admin`

This is working since the value of keyword is static.
But when I'm trying to pass the `keyword` variable to the hx-vals it's not generating params.

```
<div hx-trigger="load, every 15s" 
     hx-get="/user-list" hx-vals='{"keyword":${keyword}}'
      hx-target="this"></div>
```

generated url:`/user-list`

My question is, how to properly add the variable in the value of hx-vals?

UPDATE:

I tried this but still not working

```
<div hx-trigger="load, every 15s" hx-get="/user-list" 
hx-vals='js:{"keyword":htmx.values(htmx.find("#keyword"))}'
      hx-target="this"></div>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, do you want to include a variable or a value of an html tag?

Comment: variable and html tag value are the same. As you see the $keyword is mapped to the input tag.

Comment: Then why don't you just use `hx-include`? It's simpler.

Comment: oh man! sometimes we tend to complicate simple things. Thanks! You can post your answer so I can close this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to include a value of an html tag, you can use a rather simpler approach `hx-include`:

```
<div hx-trigger="load, every 15s" 
    hx-get="/user-list" 
    hx-include="#keyword" 
     hx-target="this">
</div>
```